# Solving Separable First Order ODE 3

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For $$iR+L\frac{di}{dt}=E$$ where R, L, and E are constants,  I needed to find the solution that satisfies $i(0)=0$. The answer I found was $i(t)=\frac{E}{R}(e^{\frac{t}{LR}}-1)$ but my textbook gives a slightly different answer and I wanted to verify which one is correct and why. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$iR+L\frac{di}{dt}=E$$ gives $\frac{di}{dt}+\frac{R}{L}i=\frac{E}{L}$ which is Linear ODE of first order.

Its solution is $i(t)=c.exp(-Rt/L)+\frac{E}{R}$. As $i(0)=0$,you will get  $c=\frac{-E}{R}$. Then $i(t)=\frac{E}{R}[-exp(-Rt/L)+1]$.